# populate an expandableListView with arrayLists

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Can anyone tell me any good links on how to do this? 
I've looked through a good 15-20 links and none have really explained anything. 
I just want to dynamically populate an `ExpandableListView` with `ArrayList`s or if theres
another way... I'd love to know.

PLEASE HELP :(!

Comment: What problems are you running into?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure an ArrayList is the right data structure to use for an ExpandableListView -- but if you mean a ArrayList of Maps that would be more appropriate. You could do that with the [SimpleExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html) class it looks like. Then use ExpandableListView.setAdapter() to couple it with your view.

Comment: Yes, that sounds much better. I'll give it a try.